# Error Building Android App with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I created a project with phone gap with simple login and was working fine with the phonegap developer app on mobile.

When I tried to build the android app using the command

```
cordova build android
```

I am getting the following error

> Error: Source path does not exist:
>   www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png

When I checked the path mentioned in the error message, I the file was not there. Instead drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png was there. So I just duplicated the file and renamed it to drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png and then I tried to build again with the command

```
cordova build android
```

and I got the same error again. And when I checked the path again, the file I added seems to be not there anymore.

Please help me solve this issue and build the app.

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

config.xml is

```html
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.g10solution.okornot" version="1.0.0">
  <name>G10 OK or NOT App</name>
  <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" platform="ios" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" platform="ios" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" platform="wp8" width="99" height="99"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" platform="wp8" width="159" height="159"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" platform="wp8" width="768" height="1280"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="150" height="150"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="30" height="30"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="50" height="50"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="620" height="300"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="44" height="44"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="106" height="106"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="70" height="70"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="71" height="71"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="170" height="170"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="360" height="360"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="310"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="150"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="744" height="360"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="1152" height="1920"/>
  </platform>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Did you tried re-adding android platform ?

Comment: Yes. But still getting the same error

Comment: What was the solution AeJey? 
I'm having the same problem with Cordova 6.5.0, Cordova platform ios 4.3.1:   Error: Source path does not exist: res/ios/icon-40.png .

Comment: It was the issue with the version of Android SDK (an older version which was already there in my PC) I was having. It worked after updating the Android SDK to the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

I've just had this issue and was able to fix this by doing 2 things :
 1. remove all of this from your config.xml

```
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" platform="ios" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" platform="ios" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" platform="ios" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" platform="ios" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" platform="ios" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" platform="ios" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" platform="ios" width="87" height="87"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" platform="wp8" width="99" height="99"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" platform="wp8" width="159" height="159"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" platform="wp8" width="768" height="1280"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="150" height="150"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="30" height="30"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="50" height="50"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="620" height="300"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="44" height="44"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="106" height="106"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="70" height="70"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="71" height="71"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="170" height="170"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="360" height="360"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="310"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" platform="windows" width="310" height="150"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="744" height="360"/>
    <splash src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" platform="windows" width="1152" height="1920"/>
  </platform>
```

(So there is no reference to images in config.xml anymore, and instead **use [cordova-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-icon)**, which makes life so much easier)

2. get the android API v23 (using the Android SDK Manager (`$ android`))

Comment: Nice! You made my day!

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue in past. you probably have a png file with name screen.png.

Create a drawable folder for 'land-xxhdpi' qualifier, "create a folder drawable-land-xxhdpi under www/res/screen/android/" and put your screen.png file under that folder. you can use the same image but you should use the image of xxhdpi resolution.

Then try to run the command

- cordova build android

Comment: I created a folder named drawable-land-xxhdpi and copied screen.png inside it. But I am still getting the same error "Error: Source path does not exist: www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png"

Comment: Are you saving it under /Platforms/android/ folder ? Can you share your folder structure, may be screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot added to the question. Please check.

Comment: Can you share your config.xml file ?

Comment: Can't see your comment. Could you please update it to the answer

Comment: Try this. <splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>   remove "www" as src attribute is relative to project directry and not www. not sure about this but give a shot.